# Why do both "[] == true" and "![] == true" evaluate to false?

Tags: javascript

I have two statements like this. Why do they both evaluate to `false`?

```js
console.log([] == true)
console.log(![] == true)
```

If `[] == true` is `false` shouldn't `![] == true` result to `true`?

Comment: No, if `[] == true` is `false`, then `[] != true` would be `true`. Negating one of the sides doesn't have the same semantics. Thing about it `3 == 2` is `false`, correct? So, why would `!3 == 2` be `true`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the way [coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) works.

The first step of coercion is to convert any non primitive types to primitive types, then using a set of rules convert the left, right or both sides to the same type. You can find these rules [here](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

In your case `[] == true`, would pass through these 4 steps:

1. `[] == true`
2. `[] == 1`
3. `"" == 1`
4. `0 == 1`

Whereas based on [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) the `!` in `![] == true` is executed first so the expression is converted to `false == true` which is obviously `false`.

You can try the [live demo](https://felix-kling.de/js-loose-comparison/) by [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) to better understand how the sameness operator works.

### In more words:

The value `![]` is `false`, because `[]` is an Object (arrays are objects) and all objects, not including `null`, are truthy. So any array, even if it is empty will always be a truthy, and the opposite of a truthy is always `false`. The easiest way to check if a value is a truthy is by using `!!`.

```js
console.log("![]: " + ![]);
console.log("!![]: " + !![]);
```

When you are using a loose comparison (using `==` instead of `===`) you are asking the JavaScript engine to first convert the values into the same type and then compare them. So what happens is the values get converted according to a set of rules, once they are the same type, they get compared though the same process as a strict equality check (`===`). The first change that `[]` goes through is to get converted to a string, the string version of an empty array is an empty string `""`, the empty string is then converted to a number, the numeric value of an empty string is `0`, since the numeric value of `true` is `1` and `0` != `1`, the final output is `false`.

```js
console.log("[] == true => `" + ([] == true) + "`");

console.log("String([]) => `" + String([]) + "`");
console.log("Number('') => `" + Number("") + "`");

console.log("Number(true) => `" + Number(true) + "`");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, could you elaborate on why `![]` evaluates to `false` if `[]` also evaluates to false?

Comment: @SepehrNazari I've added some more details to the answer

Answer (score 2):

As per the **Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm** - http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3

> Types of x and y are checked when  `x == y`  is to be checked.
>
> If no rule matches, a false is returned.

1. For  `[] == true` , rule 7 matches, so a result of `[] == ToNumber(true)` is returned i.e. `false` is returned.
2. Reason you're getting the same result for  `![] == true`, because  `![]`  returns `false`, and  `false == true`  returns  `false` .

> To get opposite result for your second operation, add a precedence (i.e. wrap) to your expression with braces.

```js
console.log(!([] == true)); // returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `![]` in the console. It's `false`.

So `![] == true` is the same as `false == true`, which is `false`.

`[] != true` is `true` though

Comment: I don't think it answers the question. The question essentially is if `[]` is `false` then why is '![]` also `false`. In mathematics and logic, the negation of `false` is `true`. So this is a valid question. The answer is complicated.

Comment: It's not complicated. `[]` is not false. You should learn about data types, coercion, casting, equality, identity, `==` and `===`. `[] == false -> true` but `[] === false -> false`. It's not mathematics. It's programming, and there are a number of ways to conceive what something "is" depending on the equality operator, and the context.

Comment: Let me try again.   
1. I didn't say `[]` is `false`. I was interpreting the question: if `[] == true` produces `false` then that *implies* `[]` is `false`. In JavaScript specification, an empty array is truthy. The question then is what's behind this contradiction. See Nick Zoum's and my answers above which explain the reason behind.  
2. Your answer started with `![]` is `false`. This bypasses why `[] == true` is false. So it doesn't answer the question.
3. Look up discrete mathematics and propositional logic. They are the foundation of programming.

Comment: You mention: `[] == false -> true` but `[] === false -> false`
Of course. But what does it have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far has addressed the main problem. [Edit: This is no longer true. See Nick Zoum's answer.]

The question essentially is this:

`[] == true` returns `false`
=> `[]` is not `true`
=> `[]` is `false` (because something not true must be false)
=> `![]` should be `true`, since negation of `false` is `true`. Then why does `![] == true` return `false`?

---

`[]` is actually truthy. (So `![]` is actually falsy.)

Still, `[] == true` returns `false` -- the reason is coercion. It's another of Javascript's gotchas.

When an array is checked for equality explicitly against a boolean value (that is, against `true` or `false`), its elements are first converted to strings and then joined together. An empty array therefore becomes `""` — therein lies the problem, because an empty string is falsy.

In brief, an empty array is truthy, but it's coerced (when being compared to a boolean value) to an empty string, which is falsy.

Note the following, which comes from https://www.nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/

> Arrays are particularly weird. If you just test it for truthyness, an
>   empty array is truthy. HOWEVER, if you compare an empty array to a
>   boolean, it becomes falsy:

```
if ( [] == false ) {
     // this code runs }

if ( [] ) {
    // this code also runs }

if ([] == true) {
    // this code doesn't run }

if ( ![] ) {
  // this code also doesn't run }
```

> (This is because when you do a comparison, its elements are turned to Strings and joined. Since it's empty, it becomes "" which is then falsy. Yea, it's weird.)

Answer (score 0):

Read https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Rule in JavaScript for The Equals Operator (==)

if

```
type(x)            type(y)                    result

1.x and y are the same type    See Strict Equality (===) Algorithm

2.null              Undefined                 true

3.Undefined           null                    true

4. Number            String                 x == toNumber(y)

5. String            Number                  toNumber(x) == y

6. Boolean           (any)                  toNumber(x) == y

7. (any)              Boolean               x == toNumber(y)

8.String or Number    Object                x == toPrimitive(y)

9.Object            String or Number          toPrimitive(x) == y

***10.otherwise…                                 false
```

Comment: Did you derive that table from the specification? It might be a good idea to add the source.

Comment: This answer is not very useful. You haven't explained how this table resolves the issue being discussed.